# How to change class object into Array List in c# windows form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, firebase

```
Product_Details result = response.ResultAs<Product_Details>();
ArrayList myarr = result;
foreach (var item in result.ToString())
{

}
```

I want to change the variable result into an array list because this variable is containing data of full table and I need to iterate it.

Comment: `foreach(var item in response.ResultAs<Product_Details>())` ? You're going to have to explain your code more

Comment: If user press Pizza button then in my database on firebase returns all the products who are sub of Pizza. THat data is retrieving in response. That data is collection means it takes record of unlimited products. So I want that data from response to store in list so that I can iterate on it

Answer (score 2):

IF i understand correctly, you are saying that the response contains multiple objects of type Product_Details. I do however need some more information; is the response coming in a JSON format (does it need to be serialized for example?).

Either way try something along the lines of this;

```
         List<Product_Details> result = new List<Product_Details>(); // make a new list
         result = response.ResultAs<List<Product_Details>>(); // assign response to list       
         foreach (Product_Details pd in result)
         {
             // use pd. to access the variable
         }

// (i kept the .ResultAs since i dont know how or what your response object is/has,but did cast it to a list explicitly)
```

If you need to find out on how to deserialize JSON objects you can start [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195795/convert-json-response-to-object-array)

As discussed in the comments you said it was in JSON format, If you are using NewtonSoft.JSON (nuget) the code would be:

```
 using (client)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(tmpUri);
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        oc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<T>>(content);
                      }
                }
```

(for the sake of clarity where this code should be i included the api call. you can of course, omit this.)

Comment: its not working as response gets data from firebase but when you are assigning result list to response then result list will have all the fields but all are showing null

Comment: If user press Pizza button then in my database on firebase returns all the products who are sub of Pizza. THat data is retrieving in response. That data is collection means it takes record of unlimited products. So I want that data from response to store in list so that I can iterate on it

Comment: in what format is the data in the response returned. I suspect JSON, as that is the most common format. If so, you need to deserialize the json to readable c#. try the link i appended to the answer. that might help.